# Algebraically transform logic expression

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, proof-writing, quantifiers

> Algebraically transform:
>
> $\neg \forall x(P(x) \wedge Q(y) \implies \exists zR(z))$
>
> to
>
> $\exists x\forall z(P(x) \wedge Q(y) \wedge \neg R(z))$
>
> Justify each step with one or more laws.

Unfortunately I don't know even how to begin. I am just learning to be familiar with some of the laws and what they do. However, this is the first time we've been asked to algebraically transform an equation with  all/some quantifiers.

I've tried Googling, but I am only finding pages of "Circuit Simplification" and examples in unfamiliar formats, different than shown.

Comment: $\neg(\forall x)p(x)$ is the same as $(\exists x)\neg p(x)$, so your first step is to change $\neg(\forall x)(P(x)\wedge Q(y) \to (\exists z)R(z))$ into $(\exists x)\neg(P(x)\wedge Q(y) \to (\exists z)R(z))$. Now you're negating an implication; what is that equivalent to? Keep going ...

Comment: The basic rules for interchanging quantifiers and negation: $\neg\forall \equiv \exists\neg, \neg\exists\equiv\forall\neg$. Happily, the bound variables are distinct, you don't have to rename $z$ to move it to the outside, and then you're left with just an open formula that's a negation of an implication, which is equivalent to the desired form.

Answer (score 0):

$\neg \forall x(P(x) \wedge Q(y) \implies \exists zR(z))$

By DeMorgan, we have
$\exists x\neg (P(x) \wedge Q(y) \implies \exists zR(z))$

Use the equivalence $(p \implies q )\iff (\neg p \vee q)$ to get
$$\exists x\neg (\neg(P(x) \wedge Q(y) )\vee \exists zR(z)) $$

Keep using your properties to continue simplifying. 
Can you take it from here?

Comment: Hrmm...DeMorgan's: $\exists x((P(x)\land Q(y))\land \neg (\exists zR(z)))$ = $\exists x\forall z(P(x)\land Q(y)\land \neg R(z))$. Is that it?

Comment: Yes.  You are correct.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with in the end:

1. $\neg \forall x(P(x)\land Q(y)\implies \exists zR(z))$
2. $\exists x\neg (P(x)\land Q(y)\implies \exists zR(z))$ DeMorgan's
3. $\exists x\neg (\neg (P(x)\land Q(y))\lor \exists zR(z))$ Implication
4. $\exists x(P(x)\land Q(y)\land \neg \exists zR(z))$ DeMorgan's
5. $\exists x(P(x)\land Q(y)\land \forall z\neg R(z))$ DeMorgan's
6. $\exists x \forall z(P(x)\land Q(y)\land \neg R(z))$ Associative

Comment: If there does not exist a value of $z$ that makes $R(z)$ true, then for all values of $z$, $\neg R(z)$.  So your first step 4 to step 5 here is correct.